# Google Cloud Function timing out after being finished

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I use the authentication trigger onCreate and the function works. Everything gets executed perfectly and in the logs it even says that the function finished in a certain amount of time. But even if it says the function finished, it still gives a timeout and says the function was killed because of an unhandled exception. Is this normal? Since the function finishes correctly, it seems weird that a timeout is still thrown and the function is still killed. It is in the emulator that I am still testing this only.

```
i  functions: Finished "createWallet" in 984.834125ms
⚠  functions: Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

I am trying to figure out if this maybe is just normal behaviour and that while new onCreate triggers are done in those 60s, the function instance will be "reused". But if not more users are created, then the function instance will be killed and a new instance will need to be started up again on the next trigger.
But it would be nice if someone could confirm this. It seems weird to get an unhandled error warning without more info. How could I fix this?

Or maybe is it because I do not have a return value?
My function makes an external http fetch and then writes to to firestore collections. What should I return in this case if a return value is needed on an onCreate authentication trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, a return value was indeed needed. For an async trigger a promise should be returned as stated in the terminate functions section of the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> - Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise. -
> - Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().
> - Terminate a synchronous function with a return; statement.